# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '*'

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy comenzando a programar en Python, y mi duda es la siguiente:

mi programa si corre, sin embargo al querer salir del bucle, me arroja el siguiente error:

```
def pcn_loop3():
    while True:
        x = int(input("Ingrese un numero ('*' para terminar): "))
        if x == '*':
            break
        elif x > 0:
            print("Numero positivo")
        elif x == 0:
            print("Igual a 0")
        else:
            print("Numero negativo")
```

> Ingrese un numero ('*' para terminar): 3
>
>   Numero positivo
>
>   Ingrese un numero ('*' para terminar): 
>
>   *Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>     File "", line 1, in 
>
>       pcn_loop3()
>
>     File "C:\01_Mis.Documentos\01 Mis Programas en Python\Mis proyectos\kk.py", line 3, in pcn_loop3
>
>       x = int(input("Ingrese un numero ('*' para terminar): "))
>   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '*'

Y no puedo hacer que salga del bucle y si le quito int a la variable x me arroja el siguiente error:

> Ingrese un numero ('*' para terminar): 3
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       pcn_loop3()
>     File "C:\01_Mis.Documentos\01 Mis Programas en Python\Mis proyectos\kk.py", line 6, in pcn_loop3
>       elif x > 0:
>   TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Como hago que salga del ciclo infinito, sin que me arroje un error...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se da porque estás casteando un `*` a int, por lo que te arroja una excepción que no estás considerando ni manejando, para que funcione tendrías que cambiar tu código a esto:

```
def pcn_loop3():
    while True:
        x = input("Ingrese un numero ('*' para terminar): ")
        if x == '*':
            break
        try:
            x = int(x)
            if x > 0:
                print("Numero positivo")
            elif x == 0:
                print("Igual a 0")
            else:
                print("Numero negativo")
        except ValueError:
            # Si no se puede castear entonces informo que lo ingresado no es un numero
            print("No es un numero")
```

Comment: Genaro, muchas gracias. me a sido de mucha utilidad la solución al problema. Te agradezco.

Comment: De nada! Para eso estamos. Si te solucionó el problema no olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta para dar por cerrada la pregunta. Saludos!